# Which PHP RPC (XML or JSON) library have you successfully used?

Tags: php, xml, json, rpc

Which PHP RPC (XML or JSON) library have you successfully used?

I have done some research but haven't been able to find one library that stands out from the others.

I've found the following:

[XML-RPC for PHP](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/)

[XML_RPC (PEAR)](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RPC/)

[JSON-RPC PHP](http://jsonrpcphp.org/)

And a few others that either don't look very active or mature.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlrpc.php works great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used XML_RPC (PEAR) successfully. I'm not personally a fan of the xml-rpc "way" but the library was simple to use and we have a few dozen clients using it daily and pulling a fair amount of data over the wire and we've never had any problems.

We aren't pushing the envelope with this at all, in any way, but i'm very happy with the library since I don't even think about it anymore. The library isn't elegant or anything but neither is php or rpc, right?

Answer (score 2):

I've written a simple XML-RPC library for PHP 5, called Ripcord. You can download it at http://ripcord.googlecode.com/. It is as easy to use as I could make it, even for the more advanced features like system.multicall. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

we've done a very RPC robust library, following with the RPC specs 100%. You can switch between JSON-RPC-2.0 and JSONP on the fly and it supports also batch requests, signed request and service method introspection basing on Dojo's RPC proposals.

1. XApp-RPC core package https://github.com/XApp-Studio/xapp-Rpc
2. Example usage : xappcommander.com

we've done this because all what was around didn't meet our license/quality requirements. Have fun.