# pull users from another wordpress remote database and display

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

hello so I have 2 wp installations with buddypress, I would like to pull the second site members remotely and display them on the first blog.
is there a way to use WP_User_Query with a different database  ?

Answer (score 0):

In most server configurations, external access to the database is not allowed, in order to increase security. Thus, direct access to the database is probably not an option.

But Wordpress has a API that is made for external access via HTTP. The API has a [`getUsers`](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Users#wp.getUsers) function that should help you.

There are several libraries that can help you make XML-RPC (the protocol of the Wordpress API) requests, see [Which PHP RPC (XML or JSON) library have you successfully used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606844/376138) for an overview.

Comment: I enabled remote mysql access so that wont be a problem. But I like your suggestion